# Slidejs working on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I have this webpage with a slidejs:
https://www.melkerhei.be/smeltkroes/audiowave.html

When going to mobile the slideshow should be on top of the page. But it doesn't.
The strangest thing is that it sometimes does work.

Neither there are no errors so I don't know where to start to find the problem.

When running it on the local server it works.

**slidejs-code**

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.slides.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#slides').slidesjs({
            navigation: false,
            start: 1,
            play: {
                auto: true
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#slides-mobile').slidesjs({
            navigation: false,
            pagination: false,
            start: 1,
            play: {
                auto: true
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mobile-artists" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-12 img_section" style="display:none;padding-top:0%;padding-left:0%;padding-right:0%;">
    <div id="slides-mobile" class="artist-pics">
        <img src="assets/img/artists/audiowave_bio.jpg">
        <img src="assets/img/artists/audiowave_bio6.jpg">
        <img src="assets/img/artists/audiowave_bio5.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

**includes**

```
<script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/isotope.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/imgloaded.js"></script>
```

Comment: When writing a question it says: The question should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**.

Comment: added the code i used

Comment: You may hide and show the divs By CSS ( Responsive Query ).